# Eclipse + PHP でローカルファイルをeclipseから apacheに実行させる方法

Tags: php, apache, eclipse

Ubuntu 17.10に、apache2 libapache2-mod-php eclipse等をインストールして
プログラムを書こうとしています。全くの初心者です。

プログラムは ~/eclipse-workspace/SamplePj1/test.php においています。
runメニューのrun configurations の PHP Serverの設定で、
URL:　http://localhost
Document Root: /home/myid/eclipse-workspace
と設定して
run configurationsのfileに/SamplePj1/test.php
を設定して 右下のrunボタンを押すと、下記のエラーが出ます。

---

Not Found

The requested URL /SamplePj1/test.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

---

apacheが/var/www/htmlディレクトリを見に行って、ファイルが無いよとエラーを
出しているのだというのはわかるのですが、
ローカルディレクトリ (/home/myid/eclipse-workspace)のファイルをeclipseから
apacheに実行させるにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

Apacheがユーザーディレクトリを扱えるように設定してやればよいと思います。
UbuntuのApacheがどんなパッケージになっているかよく知らないので、細かい設定内容は「Apache　ユーザーディレクトリ追加」などで検索して、お使いの環境に近い解説を参考にしてみてください。

例えば[Apacheのドキュメントサイト](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/howto/public_html.html)にも解説があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。モヤモヤしていたものがスッキリしました。